# Adding button to wordpress menu

Tags: php, menus, dashboard

I have learning lot new things about WordPress Development but one thing want to know there a way that I can add own button to the WordPress menu and use the custom styles.

[image]

Comment: I think you can google a little bit harder than that, right?

Comment: @ExcellentSP I did post a new topic here --> http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241016/cannot-get-email-links-to-show-using-wp-get-nav-menu-items